# Negative timespan on battery usage graph and blank WiFi data usage graph on CM12.1 after installing WhatsApp

Tags: motorola-moto-g, data-monitoring, battery-history

I recently installed CM12.1 on my Moto G 2013 XT1033. After installing WhatsApp and rebooting, the data usage meter isn't showing. The same goes for the battery usage details.

[image: battery graph with negative timespan]
[image: blank wifi usage]
[image: Data usage history]

<sup>Click image(s) for larger versions</sup>

[image: Android OS Data usage]

data usage showing up weird data cycles.

Comment: Have you set the date & time correctly? It seems that the device date is set in the future, or at least there's a discrepancy between internal date and shown date (only a guess, since I don't know how Android store the date). 315854661 seconds is around 10 years, and the date cycle showing up to 2016 is really strange.

Comment: Btw, I added your comment from the answer to add more info about the issue. Feel free to fix/improve if there's a wrong info.

Comment: There is one more thing which i came across. android os shows that there has been a small (about 3.30kb) data usage in a future year, namely the year 2025.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bug. Just try to restart your phone a couple times, and it will be ok.

Comment: It may be, but do you have link(s) to back the claim?

Comment: i did a clean install today again. same problem persists. any of you having this problem?

Comment: i noticed something: on installing whatsapp and rebooting phone, whatsapp encounters an error saying that phone date is inaccurate. after that the data usage history messes up.

Comment: Hy guys, i research a little and i found this.  http://prntscr.com/7hktdx

Comment: what about the data usage bug?

Comment: i don't know man. i found just for batery, i didn't found anything for data usage. 

Is that helped you for battery?

Comment: Yes, but the fix is not persistent.

Answer (score -1):

It's a  bug buddy and I had my download percentage shown 157% on CM once. Restarting did the trick.

Comment: Restarting isn't really helping. And this keeps happening as soon as i install whatsapp.